# Issue with setting up SSL on magento

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin-panel, ssl

I am having issue with setting up website on https from http. I am using Magento ver. 2.1.9.

```
Current Settings:
web/unsecure/base_url --> http:// .......
web/secure/base_url --> https://...........
web/secure/use_in_frontend --> 1
web/secure/use_in_adminhtml --> 1
```

Issue
Magento admin login page -- The page is redirecting too many times.

Magento Front -- All the URLs like navigation links & form actions are still using http. And customer login page is redirecting too many times which leads to page crash.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `web/unsecure/base_url` to `https://...` - in practice I've never experienced any issue if doing so since usually store owners, when owning a SSL certificate, are willing to secure all URLs anyway. Furthermore you should check for any rewrite rules in you .htaccess/vhosts/webspace panel that may be responsible for the http->https (or https->http in your case?) redirects.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried it but it didn't work for me the change after doing this was that homepage was also getting too many redirects.

Comment: checked your webspace config as well? Usually these panels come with options to allow you to directly redirect for example from _http_ to _https_.